# COUNTIF other google sheet's A2 row by IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I am looking for a formula that will help me count other google sheet's D column matched with the current sheet row.

wait I am explaining!!!

I want to count the reg no. of D column of the student of (RM responses 20.08.2020) Sheet
according to that students reg no. (A2 row) value of (Attendance Counter) sheet.
So that I can scroll it down according to row.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcMI6.jpg

here is the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mWtCKQggKUoGAn9td5nkjva6UBK5WHtq_NHBd-lEj8c/edit#gid=1023365212", " Form Responses 1!$D:$D; "A2"))"))
```

Here are links of the sheets:
Link (Attendance Counter): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PKk0y1yoi0smAYKfGwMkLSUkJLWtb0JwmWIVKdnOKoY/edit#gid=306895548

Link (RM Responses): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mWtCKQggKUoGAn9td5nkjva6UBK5WHtq_NHBd-lEj8c/edit#gid=1023365212

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("1mWtCKQggKUoGAn9td5nkjva6UBK5WHtq_NHBd-lEj8c", 
 "Form Responses 1!D:D"), A2)
```

[image]